# Hollowed text inside a solid

Tags: text-object

I am trying to make a word appear in the empty space of a solid cube. Very similar to the Marvel logo attached. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- If you start from a logo, you first need to import it in SVG format. Keep in mind that it will be very small in the center of your scene so you may not see it at first and you'll have to scale it a lot.
- If you start from your own text, you can type it in Blender: Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Text*, go in *Edit* mode, type your text, if necessary choose the font in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Font*, and press on the *Load a new font from file* button to browse into your own fonts.
- Then convert it to a mesh with an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
- Simplify it in *Edit* mode with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.
- Extrude it on the Z axis: <kbd>E</kbd>.
- Create your parallelepiped, put your text on it.
- Give your parallelepiped a *Boolean* modifier / *Difference* mode and choose the text as *Object*.
- You can keep the text and make it transparent in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire* and, for the render, in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycle Settings* settings (deactivate all the options), or you can apply the modifier.

Is it what you want?

[image]

Comment: Might be worth adding a note that you don't *need* SVG format if don't have it and are able to model the text yourself.

Comment: oh ok you're right, done

Comment: Did you mean to addt he word "parallelepiped"?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Ok, I've just googled it, but I'd never heard of the term. Not quite sure why you would use such an obtuse term instead of 'mesh' or 'object'.

Comment: I didn't want him to be lost with a "add a mesh"... what would I've been talking about? "Parallelepiped" is not so uncommon, at least in my country, sorry if it sounded obtuse...    :/